# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output' | popen & PIPE

Tags: python, attributes, pipe, popen, python-2.6

I am writing a script and got it to work run and did everything I wanted it to. I want to add in a function to have my dictionary sleep after checking it but when I add the time.sleep(5)   <-(5 seconds) it now throws me this error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'
```

On this line of code

```
 print ("INFO: checking kswapd number of process and cputime, check for TIME colume for how busy kswapd was" +  subprocess.check_output("ps -C kswapd0 -C kswapd1 -C kswapd2 -C kswapd3 -C kswapd4  -o pid,ppid,stime,etime,time,pcpu,args", shell=True))
```

Any one know how I could use Pipe and Popen to get around using subprocess.check_output?

Or here is where I put the time.sleep() if you see that its not the right for any reason

```
with open("/proc/meminfo") as f:
sample1 = []
for line in f:
    if line.startswith(pre):
        v = line.rsplit(None, 2)[1]
        sample1.append(v)
        time.sleep(5)
```

I am in Python v2.6,  and no I cannot upgrade otherwise I would!
Thanks for any input!

Comment: Did you call your python program `subprocess.py` by any chance?  Is your indentation wrong on the question or in your program?  The body of the code after the `with` should be indented.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `subprocess` module from Python's standard library and this module indeed doesn't have an attribute `check_output`.

Assuming that you are using it like this:

```
import subprocess

child = Popen(["mycmd", "myarg"], stdout=PIPE)
```

you should call `child.communicate()[0]` and not `subprocess.check_output()` to see the output in Python 2.6.

Comment: What are you talking about? Perhaps you are using a very old version of Python.

Comment: @LtWorf OP says in the question that he is using Python 2.6 and can't upgrade. There's no `check_output` in subprocess module in Python 2.6. I indeed had a erroneously pasted `.check_output()` as it's absent on the Popen instance as well.

Answer (score 2):

From the subprocess documentation :

```
output = Popen(["mycmd", "myarg"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Ho wait, maybe i didn't get all the question. Is it `time.sleep(5)` that throws you this error ?

Comment: yes it is. if I comment it out it works fine but when I keep it, it throws the error

Comment: This is weird... It should not happen. Are you sure that your install of python site-packages is not a downgrade of the Python2.7 or higher site-packages ?

Comment: Also are you sure there's not any errors in your `import time` ? (like another python file or whatever) I do not find anything about this message